# Unable to login using new mysql user added via phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

On my computer yesterday I installed 12.04 and applied all updates. I have installed lamp on this system using following command `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin` . I created a new user from phpmyadmin and given that user all the global privileges, but I am not able to login using that new user, I have also restarted the mysql service, reload the privileges, but still its not working. It used to work fine in Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: try in terminal:  mysql -u username -p  [hit enter and give appropriate password]. Let use know the error message.

Comment: The problem is that during the creation of user, I selected anyhost. But then I deleted the user and selected localhost and now its working.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql is a bit odd in the fact that you if you want to login from that server only it is 'username'@'localhost' but if you need to login in from another server also you have to add a second user entry 'username'@'ipaddress' or 'username'@'%' for any host (apart from local host) and then grant privileges user each variation.

```
grant all on mydb.* to 'username'@'localhost'......... ; grant all on mydb.* to 'username'@'%' ......;
```